# symmetric quasi-uniformity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

A quasi-uniformity $U$ will be called symmetric provided that $U = U^{-1}$, that is, provided that it is a uniformity. Otherwise it will be called nonsymmetric. It is readily seen  that the supremum and infimum of an arbitrary family of uniformities in $(q(X),⊆)$ is a uniformity.

If $U_1$ and $U_2$ are two quasi-uniformities on a set $X$ and $U_1 ⊆ U_2$, then we say that $U_2$ is finer than $U_1$, resp., that $U_1$
is coarser than $U_2$.

For a quasi-uniformity $U$ on a set $X$, by $U_{ω}$ we shall denote the finest totally bounded quasi-uniformity coarser than $U$ on $X$.

Let $Q$ be a nonsymmetric quasi-uniformity on a set $X$ that is proximally symmetric. (For instance, we
can choose any proximally discrete anti-atom of $(q(X),⊆))$ We are going to show that the quasiuniformities
$Q_{ω} × Q $and $Q^{-1} × Q_{ω}$ are both proximally symmetric, but that their supremum $Q^{-1} × Q$ is not proximally symmetric.

> Why is the conjugate quasi-uniformity of $Q^{-1} × Q$ on X ×X , $Q×Q^{−1}$?